# Custom file name pattern in ADF sink

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a requirement where I need the output file name to be in format - <Test_YYYYMMDD_NNNN>.txt. Output file will have multiple partitions.

NNNN represent partition sequence.

Example-

1.Test_20220306_0001.txt
2.Test_20220307_0002.txt

Please let me know if this is achievable. Currently, I am getting the file in format Test_20220306-000001.txt which is the default spark schema.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the default Spark partitioning schema will not be ignored and it will automatically add the `-00001/-00002/..` partition value to each partition file name when using **file name option** as `pattern` in sink settings.

If you know the number of partitions value, you can use `per partition` in **File name option** in sink settings and provide each partitioned file name dynamically.

[image]

**filename parameter** contains `concat('Test_',replace(toString(currentDate()),'-',''))`

[image]

Output files:

[image]